# PySide6 QListWidget dragging a row to its index deletes the row

Tags: qlistwidget, pyside6

```
import sys, os
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from ui_listitem import *


class myItem(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.ui = Ui_rootWidget() # this ui just have 2 text labels horizontal aligned
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


class myList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)

        for i in range(10):
            wi = QListWidgetItem(self)
            wi.widget = myItem(self)
            wi.widget.ui.label1.setText(f'text{i}')
            wi.widget.ui.label2.setText(f'text{i}')
            wi.setSizeHint(wi.widget.sizeHint())
            self.addItem(wi)
            self.setItemWidget(wi, wi.widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = myList()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

result:
[image]

uh..I don't know what it happened. What should I do to get it to work?
I read a post([InternalMove in QListWidget makes item disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291628/internalmove-in-qlistwidget-makes-item-disappear)). I tried `setDefaultDropAction(Qt.TargetMoveAction)` or `setMovement(QListView.Free)` or both but not worked.
I am using python 3.9.7, pyside 6.2.1, on Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.1348 build.

Addition.
A similar but not identical disappearance occurs in a QListView without a custom widget.

```
import sys, os
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class myDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QSize(350, 35)

class myList(QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.delegate = myDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)

        for i in range(10):
            item = QStandardItem(f'text{i}')
            self.model.appendRow(item)

        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = myList()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

result:
[image]

I tried `setDefaultDropAction` with `Qt.MoveAction, Qt.CopyAction or Qt.TargetMoveAction` but all not worked.
Are these all originally intended? Please let me know how to move items in listview or listwidget without disappearing. Or maybe it's impossible?

Comment: If you try to resize the window after drag&drop, do widgets show again?

Comment: @musicamante I tried it now but not working

Comment: I tested it and it works for Qt5, so it *may* be a Qt6 bug (which I cannot test). If you also have PySide2 (Qt5) or PyQt5 installed, can you test it and verify if the issue is still reproducible? If you tell us the OS you're on it might be helpful for others that could try on their own and eventually confirm it.

Comment: @musicamante I tested the first case with PySide2 (5.15.2) and also the problems occured. I tested on Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.1348 build.

Comment: I'm confused right now.. Does it only happen to me..??

Comment: I'm on Linux, so the OS might be an important aspect (but that seems strange, as your code is quite "standard"). Can you test it on a different OS, possibly with a virtual machine?

Comment: @musicamante I haven't tried virtual machines yet. And the computer specs are not good, so it seems difficult right now.

Comment: I tested with PyQt5, a disappearing problem exists too. It is impossible that this kind of problem is not yet known to people. so I think something wrong with me but I don't have any idea what it is... :(

Comment: the frozen first script was tested on windows 11 with pyside2, pyside6 and pyqt5, identical the problem still occurred. But the script was frozen on my machine, so I'm not sure the test have any meanings.